# Reducing code duplication in Golang

Tags: go, interface, refactoring, code-duplication

I'm having trouble find the "go-way" to solve a code duplication issue. Here's the problem. Consider the following:

```
type (
  WithKey interface {
    key() string
  }

  SharedFunctionality interface {
    WithKey
    MethodA() string
    MethodB() string
    // ... etc ...
  }

  FirstType struct { ... }
  SecondType struct { ... }
  // ... etc ...
)
func (ft *FirstType) key() string { ... }
func (st *SecondType) key() string { ... }
```

Now, the methods in `SharedFunctionality` they only depend on the results of the `key()` method. I could implement them like the following:

```
func runMethodA(k WithKey) string {
  key := k.key()
  // do something and return a string
}
func runMethodB(k WithKey) string {
  key := k.key()
  // do something else and return a string
}

func (ft *FirstType) MethodA() string { return runMethodA(ft) }
func (ft *FirstType) MethodB() string { return runMethodB(ft) }
func (st *SecondType) MethodA() string { return runMethodA(st) }
func (st *SecondType) MethodB() string { return runMethodB(st) }
```

What I dislike about this approach is that, as I add more types (ThirdType, FourthType, etc) or as I add more methods to SharedFunctionality, I have to add tons of boilerplate code... specifically, for M methods in SharedFunctionality, and N types, I would have to spell out M*N one-liners like the 4 above.

What I would *love* to do is something like:

```
func (k WithKey) MethodA() string {
  key := k.key()
  // do something
}
```

In other words: I'd love to define a method on an Interface type. Meaning: all objects that implement "WithKey" would automatically get `MethodA() string`, `MethodB() string`, etc, therefore they would automatically implement the `SharedFunctionality` interface. Something like *default methods* in *Java interfaces*.

However, I know it's impossible to define a method in an Interface type...

What's the go-way of solving this problem?

I've seen an approach where I would create a struct with an anonymous field of the interface type, and then implement the methods there:

```
type SharedFuncStruct struct {
  WithKey
}
func (sfs *SharedFuncStruct) MethodA() string {
  key := sfs.key()
  // whatever
}
// same for MethodB()
```

Then to use it, I would do something like:

```
first := ... getFirstTypeValue()
sfs := &SharedFuncStruct{first}
sfs.MethodA() // etc
```

This looks like it could work, but it still feels like too much boilerplate code.

Any other alternatives?

Comment: You've pretty much outlined your options. And see dave's answer below. And think about this: what would happen, if a concrete type would already have a `MethodA()` method besides `key()`? At least _embedding_ makes it unambiguous what `MethodA()` would mean (at the _"shallowest depth"_).

Comment: Your question is essentially "how do I do implementation inheritance and virtual methods in go", but I think perhaps you've got an xy problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . If you describe a little context of what you're doing, there's probably a solution that isn't rooted in java-style object-oriented design that'll fit better in go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun fact: you can embed interfaces into structs, and the struct then automatically fulfills that interface.  You can use this to effectively define methods on interfaces:

https://play.golang.org/p/ZufTOzr9ig

```
type (
    WithKey interface {
        key() string
    }

    SharedFunctionality interface {
        WithKey
        MethodA() string
        MethodB() string
    }

    KeyHolder struct {
        WithKey
    }

    FirstType struct { ... }
    SecondType struct { ... }
)

func (k *KeyHolder) MethodA() string {
    key := k.key()
    // ...
}

func (k *KeyHolder) MethodB() string {
    key := k.key()
    // ...
}

func NewSharedFunctionality(w WithKey) SharedFunctionality {
    return &KeyHolder{w}
}

func (ft *FirstType) key() string { ... }
func (st *SecondType) key() string { ... }
```

In this case, the `KeyHolder` struct embeds the `WithKey` interface, and thus can hold anything that has the `key() string` method (which both `FirstType` and `SecondType` have).  You can then define `MethodA` and `MethodB` on that struct, and that struct will then fulfill both the `WithKey` interface (because it embeds it) and the `SharedFunctionality` interface, using whatever key is returned by the embedded `WithKey`.

In other words, instead of wrapping `FirstType` in `WithKey` and then in `SharedFunctionality` (meaning `FirstType` itself has to define `key()`, `MethodA()`, and `MethodB()`), you wrap `FirstType` in `WithKey`, then embed it (as a `WithKey` interface) in some other structure that exists solely to define those default methods `MethodA` and `MethodB`, which then fulfills the `SharedFunctionality` interface.

Comment: I like this approach. It still like I have to type *more* than I would expect (ie, doing the `NewSharedFunctionatily(firstTypeInstance)` so I can call my `.MethodA()`), but seems like it's the best I will get. I like Dave's approach as well, but, at least for now, it seems that this solution works better for me (ie, having an object implementing the methods, instead of having to call functions on a package). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you need to extract a package.  The way I would have the function is

```
package keyed

type hasKey interface {
    Key() string
}

func MethodA(k hasKey) string {
    key := k.Key()
    // whatever
}

func MethodB(k hasKey) string {
    key := k.Key()
    // whatever
}
```

and then

```
package your_package

import "keyed"

type (
    FirstType struct { ... }
    SecondType struct { ... }
)

func (ft *FirstType) Key() string { ... }
func (st *SecondType) Key() string { ... }

func main() {
    first := &FirstType{}
    second := &SecondType{}
    keyed.MethodA(first)
    keyed.MethodA(second)
    keyed.MethodB(first)
    keyed.MethodB(second)
}
```

Comment: thanks! It definitely reduces the amount of boilerplate code. I'll certainly think of creating packages for certain scenarios. For the specific scenario I'm working with right now, Kaedys' suggestion seems a bit better -- I'll accept his solution; but thanks for your solution as well, very elegant and useful. +1!